Rollup utility functions duplicated in multiple component files
Suppose there are 2 basic component Button and Checkbox which is used by other bigger components by import.
When I check the bundle file, it shows the code is duplicated in each bigger component.

The same is happening for utility functions as well.
To fix it, I made few changes in the rollup config.
{
    input: ["src/lib/index.tsx"],
    output: [
      {
        file: "./dist/lib/index.cjs.js",
        format: "iife",
        name: "util",
        sourcemap: true,
        exports: "named",
        strict: false,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      css(),
      image(),
      url({
        // by default, rollup-plugin-url will not handle font files
        include: ["**/*.ttf"],
        // setting infinite limit will ensure that the files
        // are always bundled with the code, not copied to /dist
        limit: Infinity,
      }),
      peerDepsExternal(),
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      copy({
        targets: [{ src: "src/custom.d.ts", dest: "dist" }],
      }),
      typescript({
        tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json",
        exclude: ["**/*.stories.tsx", "**/*.stories.ts"],
        declaration: false,
      }),
      // terser(),
      analyzer(), // Generate bundle analysis report
    ],
    external: ["fs"],
  },

combined utility code in a util file and changed library src code to use it -
import { cn } from "utils"; // earlier it was - import { cn } from "@/src/utils";
It is working fine but I'm not sure if this is the best way.
What would be the better way to reduce the duplicates?
